# UI doesn't update when mutableStateOf changes

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have @Composable item - ThumbButton and Text which displays current likes number. When I click button I want to increment likes number. I don't know why it doesn't work

```
val likesCounter = remember { mutableStateOf(0)}

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        ThumbButton(
            iconSize = sizeButton,
            isSelected = isActive,
            onClick = { likesCounter.value = likesCounter.value+1 }
        )

        Text(text = "($likesCounter)")
    }
```

Comment: Please, be more precise... What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Is the compilation failing? Does it not displaying the number? Is it always displaying the same number?...

Comment: provided code seems fine, the problem is probably in `ThumbButton`. Make sure `isActive` is true, and that `onClick` is actually getting called. If this didn't help, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: At least, you need to replace "($likesCounter)" with "(${likesCounter.value})"

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the `value` property while displaying it?

```
Text(text = "(${likesCounter.value})")
```